# Wrong statement for dividing float number by another float number

Tags: python

I've a float number which is logically divisible by another float number; but Python gives me **false** statement for that!?

I tried other cases where I divided  float numbers by other float numbers, and I noticed that works only when the **tenths decimal** for denominators are **0** or **5**!?...so is there a way to fix this issue and get a **True** statement?

56.00 % 11.20 == 0

Result:

**false**

Comment: Consider that 11.2 == 11.199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875

Comment: `print(56%11.2)` gives `3.552713678800501e-15`, so it's not `==0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're not doing a normal division. You're doing what's called a [modulus division](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-a-modulo-operator-in-python/).

Second of all, as suggested in the comment by @harold, in computers, 11.2 might not be equal to 11.199999999999999999999999999; they can be seen as different numbers (check [this link](https://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=049049046050) to see the most accurate representation of 11.2 in binary format). As you can see `11.1999999999999992894572642399` (the binary representation for 11.2) is not equal to `11.199999999999999999999999999` (they differ in the 14th place)

You could try doing [round()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) to force it to have a finite number of decimals and check against that.

Try this:

```py
round(56.00 % 11.20, 2) == 0.0
```

That should give True.

Comment: https://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=049049046050

Comment: I made wrong operation by using round() function before dividing these two numbers and it give me false statement,...by doing correction and using round() after division it works and that solve my issue.

Comment: Yeah, Sorry, I got a work call while I was answering, so I posted the answer without enough clarification...